# Go net/http URL escaping

Tags: go, http

I'm writing some code to pull results from an API.  The specific URL I need to hit is:

`https://apiurl.example/api/DeviceService/Devices?$filter=Type eq 1000&$top=100`

When I paste this into a browser, it's encoded as:

`https://apiurl.example/api/DeviceService/Devices?$filter=Type%20eq%201000&$top=500`

The above URL works correctly.  When I try to encode the same URL using Go's net/url package, the dollar signs and the spaces are encoded in a different manner and the resulting URL doesn't work.  Below is some code that demonstrates my problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI("https://apiurl.example")
    u.Path = "api/DeviceService/Devices"

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Set("$filter", "type eq 1000")
    q.Add("$top", "100")
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    fmt.Println(req.URL.String())
}
```

The output from this code is:

```
https://apiurl.example/api/DeviceService/Devices?%24filter=type+eq+1000&%24top=100
```

Is there a method for achieving the same encoding as the browser generates?  If not, is there a way to pass a pre-escaped URL as a request so that Go doesn't try to reencode it?

Comment: "If not, is there a way to pass a pre-escaped URL as a request so that Go doesn't try to reencode it?" Sure, set `req.URL.RawQuery` to the desired query string, rather than creating it dynamically using `q.Encode()`.

Comment: Wow, I really went down the maze of twisty little passages there!  I could have sworn I started off trying that but I must have been using the unencoded version.  Thanks, it's working fine now.

Comment: Having broken it again, I've now realised my issue was with url.JoinPath(cfg.API.URL, path).  It seems that using url.JoinPath to construct a URL results in the URL being reencoded with broken "$" characters.